# Outlook 2007/2010 adds random line breaks/white space to HTML E-Mail

Tags: outlook, whitespace, html-email, outlook-2007, line-breaks

**Edit, the issue only exists in the preview pane of the Outlook Web App**

I have tried just about everything, but I cannot seem to rid the white spaces/line breaks that Outlook 2007/2010 renders in its preview box on the right side of the screen. When you double-click the e-mail from the inbox list, the HTML loads perfectly. However, when it is displayed in the split inbox list/e-mail preview window, line breaks/white spaces are generated.

I have tried every trick in the book. border-collapse, border=0, display:block, cell-spacing/cell-padding:0, !important, etc. Nothing works.

Here is what I am complaining about. (I have blacked out everything for privacy sake) :

1. 209.67.20.161/email/linebreaks.png
2. 209.67.20.161/email/linebreaks2.png
3. 209.67.20.161/email/linebreaks3.png

It might be the "Printed Page Limit (Microsoft Word)" that is referred to in this article:

www.emailonacid.com/blog/details/C13/horizontal_spacing_issues_in_outlook_2007_and_2010

But, I don't think so because there are some line breaks very close to each other.

BTW, I am slicing an image in photoshop and saving for web devices.

Here is the sliced image: http://209.67.20.161/email/slices.png

Be my savior...

Link to my HTML: http://209.67.20.161/email/email_sliced_forss.html

You can send the HTML e-mail to your own outlook inbox by using ctrlq.org/html-mail and copy and pasting the source of my HTML in the box after selecting HTML editer.

Comment: I have never used leftmargin topmargin for html emails. You should remove them, further I also think that you have an unnecessary height for td, given that image has its own height. you can remove td height as well.

Answer (score 4):

Style your html emails like in this example and it will render perfectly in all major clients even the old ones like lotus notes.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
        <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
        <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <title>Untitled Document</title>

<style media="all" type="text/css">
table td
{
border-collapse: collapse;
}
</style>
    </head>

    <body>
    <table width="680" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
        <tr>
            <td width="20" align="left" valign="top" rowspan="2" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" style="font-size: 10px; font-family: arial; line-height:170px;">&nbsp;</td>
            <td width="300" height="170" rowspan="2" align="left" valign="top">
                <img src="another image" alt="" width="300" height="170" border="0"></td>
            <td width="33" align="left" valign="top" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" style="font-size: 10px; font-family: arial; line-height:140px;">&nbsp;</td>
            <td width="327" colspan="2" align="left" valign="top" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" style="font-size: 14px; font-family: arial; color:#5D5B5C; line-height: 16px;">some exemple text here</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td width="33" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" style="font-size: 10px; font-family: arial; line-height:30px;">&nbsp;</td>
            <td width="138" height="30" align="left" valign="top"><a href="some link here" target="_blank"><img src="image here" alt="details" width="138" height="30" border="0"></a></td>
            <td width="189" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" style="font-size: 10px; font-family: arial; line-height:30px;">&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Here is a link to another post where I explained how to use empty TD cells instead of spacers.  [HTML Emails - Empty Tables/TR/TD as spacers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7601442/html-emails-empty-tables-tr-td-as-spacers/10517579#10517579)

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `style="line-height:your-image-size px;"` in the `<td>`; also, inside the image tag use  `style="display:block;"`